# why i am facing with problem when i try to change columns to 0 an 1?

Tags: python, pandas, datatables, data-science, nan

```
data.head()
```

| experience | stay |
| --- | --- |
| No relevent experience | 0 |
| Has relevent experience | 1 |
| No relevent experience | 0 |
| Has relevent experience | 1 |
| No relevent experience | 0 |

```
data['experience'] = data['experience'].map({'Has relevent experience':True, 'No relevent experience':False})
data.head()
```

| experience | stay |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | 0 |
| NaN | 1 |
| NaN | 0 |
| NaN | 1 |
| NaN | 0 |

Why shows NaN here???

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some whitespaces in your column. Try to use `.str.strip` before the mapping:

```py
data['experience'] = data['experience'].str.strip()
data['experience'] = data['experience'].map({'Has relevent experience':True, 'No relevent experience':False})
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
   experience  stay
0       False     0
1        True     1
2       False     0
3        True     1
4       False     0
```

Comment: It only works for 'True' and 'False', what about 1 and 0? Is there any method that can work for all of them?

Comment: @AshrafBadalov Do you want to convert `True`/`False` to `0`/`1`? Then you can do `data['experience'] = data['experience'].astype(int)` as last command.

Comment: It still shows NaN, anyway thank you for the help